# Помощь с JS кодом (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Есть код из Woo нужно сделать так, чтобы при активном radio изменялся фон у `li`, в котором он находится. Код прилагаю:

```
<ul  id="shipping_method">
                <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
                    <li class="smli">
                        <?php
                            printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method spm" %4$s />
                                <label for="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s">%5$s</label>',
                                $index, sanitize_title( $method->id ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );

                            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там данные обновляюся через ajax, поэтому нужен такой код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function setClassShipping() {
        $('ul#shipping_method li').removeClass('foo');
        $('ul#shipping_method li input[checked="checked"]').closest('li').addClass('foo');
    }

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        setClassShipping();
    });

    setClassShipping();
});
```

Вместо класса `foo` подставьте нужный, и задайте ему желаемый фон.

Код протестирован, работает на стандартной теме twentyseventeen.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли!